# How to see resulting Query string that has been built with SQLiteDataBase.query()?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

For Debugging purposes I'd like to log my resulting Query that I generate with something like this:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor c = db.query(
    TABLE_NAME,
    null,
    selection,
    selectionArgs,
    null,
    null,
    null
);
```

Is there any way to get the generated Query String?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internally `SQLiteDatabase` uses `SQLiteQueryBuilder`. You can use its [`buildQueryString()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteQueryBuilder.html#buildQueryString(boolean,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) to generate the query string and `rawQuery(sql, selectionArgs)` to ensure the very same query is executed.

Comment: This doesn't take selection Arguments though. The only method that would be applicable seems to be buildQuery() but the version with selection Arguments is deprecated and the docs say that it doesn't actually perform any substitution.

Comment: You supply the selection args when actually running the query. The `?` placeholders are part of the SQL.

Comment: Yes isn't rawQuery using some internal method for substituting the `?` as well? I kinda need access to that... or write it myself?

Comment: Parameters are bound in the sqlite C API level and never substituted in the SQL string. http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html

Comment: Ok thanks. Guess I'll just have to use the mentioned way to get the parameterized String and substitute the data myself.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? If you don't like `?` in your SQL, don't put it there to begin with, and remember to escape your literals.